# Lunar Landing game. Controls aren't working

Tags: java, awt, processing, keylistener

I have to recreate the lunar landing game in processing for an assignment. The controls are not working at all, and I cannot find the mistake in my code. Also, I am a beginner in processing and java.

```
int posx, posy;
//initial velocity
float vx,vy;
// gravity
float gravity = 0.05; 
boolean moveLeft, moveRight, moveUp;

void setup() {
   size(500, 500);
   background(0);
     //inital position
    posx =int(random(width)); //position of the left vertex of our ship
    posy =20; // position of the bottom vertex of our ship
    moveLeft = moveRight = moveUp= false;
    //initial velocity
    vx=vy=1;
}

void draw() {
  noStroke();
  background(0);

fill(255,255,255);
rect(0,470,width,30);
fill(255,0,0);
rect(200,470,100,30);

moveKeys();
moveShip();
drawShip();
}

void drawShip() {

fill(169,169,169);
rect(posx,posy,50,25);

fill(255,255,255);
rect(posx+20,posy-10,10,10);

fill(105,105,105);
rect(posx+20,posy+25,10,5);

 stroke(255,255,255);
 strokeWeight(2);
 line(posx+2,posy+25,posx+2, posy+40);

 stroke(255,255,255);
 strokeWeight(2);
 line(posx+48,posy+25,posx+48, posy+40);
}

void moveShip() {

 // Detecting collisions
     if (posx + 25 > width - 1 ||
       posx - 25 < 0)
       vx *= -1;
     if ( posy - 12.5 < 0)
       vy *= -1;
    if ( posy + 50 > height-1) 
       vx=vy=0;

 //update position      
    posx += vx;
    posy += vy;

}

void update() {
   posx += vx;
   posy += vy;
}

void keyPressed() {
 if (key==CODED) {
    switch (keyCode) {
       case UP:
        moveUp = true; break;
      case LEFT:
       moveLeft = true; break;
      case RIGHT:
        moveRight = true;  break;    
    }
  }  
}

void moveKeys() {
    if (moveLeft) translate(posx-= vx, 0);     
    if (moveRight) translate(posx+= vx, 0);
    if (moveUp) { thrust(); }
}

void thrust() {
   if (vy  < 1) vy += 0.1;
}
```

It is expected that the spaceship lands in the landing area (in red) and that's when the game should restart. However, so far I have only used the gravity feature and can't move the spaceship around.

Comment: Have you tried [debugging your code](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging)? Which line of code is not triggering the way you expected? Can you start with a simpler example that just prints a hard-coded message to the console when the user presses a key? Try to narrow your problem down to a [mcve] instead of posting your full sketch. Good luck.

Comment: Where did you set this component to be focusable, and take actions to gain the input focus? NVM - post the MCVE as suggested by @KevinWorkman & it will become clear. General tip: For Swing, we typically use [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) rather than the lower level `KeyListener`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a few problems in your code.

Firstly, Processing doesn't recognize user holding the key, program just repeatedly calls keyPressed(). It's a great idea to use booleans to store information about the arrow keys. What you're missing is method keyReleased(), that would put the boolean back on false.

Secondly, if you want to make your game look realistic, you need to put there the real time somewhere. Processing has really useful method millis(), that returns time in milliseconds from the start of the program. So whenever you're updating speed or position, you need to multiply the desired change of that by the timestep.

Some other bad things I see in your code are for example the posx and posy integers. They need to be floating point numbers to work correctly. Drawing of the ship is not really precise - actually I don't think that posx and posy are left and bottom vertex of the ship as intended. Take a look at the drawing methods at [processing site](https://processing.org) to see what they are doing.

Here is the remade code:

```
// ship position
float posx, posy;
// ship velocity
float vx,vy;
// gravity
float gravity;
// user input
boolean moveLeft, moveRight, moveUp;
// time
float timelast = 0, timenow, timeelapsed;

void setup() {

    size(500, 500);
    background(0);

    //inital position
    posx = 225;//int(random(width - 50)); //position of the left vertex of our ship
    posy = 200; // position of the bottom vertex of our ship
    // initial user input
    moveLeft = moveRight = moveUp= false;
    // initial velocity
    vx = vy = 10;
    // gravity
    gravity = 10;
    timelast = millis();
}

void draw() {

    noStroke();
    background(0);

    fill(255,255,255);
    rect(0,470,width,30);
    fill(255,0,0);
    rect(200,470,100,30);

    updateTime();
    userInput();
    moveShip();
    drawShip();
}

void updateTime() {

    timelast = timenow;
    timenow = millis();
    timeelapsed = timenow - timelast;
}

void drawShip() {

    fill(169,169,169);
    rect(posx,posy,50,25);

    fill(255,255,255);
    rect(posx+20,posy-10,10,10);

    fill(105,105,105);
    rect(posx+20,posy+25,10,5);

    stroke(255,255,255);
    strokeWeight(2);
    line(posx+2,posy+25,posx+2, posy+40);

    stroke(255,255,255);
    strokeWeight(2);
    line(posx+48,posy+25,posx+48, posy+40);
}

void userInput() {

    if (moveLeft)
        vx -= 100 * timeelapsed / 1000;
    if (moveRight)
        vx += 100 * timeelapsed / 1000;
    if (moveUp)
        vy -= 100 * timeelapsed / 1000;
}

void moveShip() {

    vy += gravity * timeelapsed / 1000;

    posx += vx * timeelapsed / 1000;
    posy += vy * timeelapsed / 1000;

    // Detecting collisions
    if (posx + 50 >= width || posx <= 0)
        vx *= -1;
    if (posy - 25 <= 0)
        vy *= -1;
    if (posy + 50 >= height) 
        vx=vy=0;
}

void keyPressed() {

    if (key==CODED) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case UP:
                moveUp = true;
                break;
            case LEFT:
                moveLeft = true;
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                moveRight = true;
                break;    
        }
    }  
}

void keyReleased() {

    if (key==CODED) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case UP:
                moveUp = false;
                break;
            case LEFT:
                moveLeft = false;
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                moveRight = false;
                break;    
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The code is doing exactly what I want it to do, I checked my mistakes and I will keep them in mind for next time :)